# Putting Variable in PHP Glob Function

Tags: php, glob

This seems like it should be easy, but nothing I've tried worked.

```
$glob = glob("{04-19-2017,04-20-2017,04-21-2017}/*.xml", GLOB_BRACE);
```

works perfectly.

But how I'm doing things is using a `_GET` to dynamically produce a `$date` variable.

I've tried...

```
$date = '04-19-2017,04-20-2017,04-21-2017';

// failed glob attempts
$glob = glob("{'.$date.'}/*.xml", GLOB_BRACE);
$glob = glob("{$date.}/*.xml", GLOB_BRACE);
$glob = 'glob("{' . $date . '}/*.xml"', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Like I said this should be super simple, but I'm running out of ideas :/

How do I get the variable in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$glob = glob("{$date}/*.xml", GLOB_BRACE);
```

or

```
$glob = glob('{'.$date.'}/*.xml', GLOB_BRACE);
```

If you put a variable between `" "` the variable will be used

If you put a variable between `' '` the variable will be handled as a string

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thank you! And for the edits. I was going to comment, but then you made the edit with the correct answer for me.  original `$glob = glob("{$date}/*.xml", GLOB_BRACE);` did not work at all but `$glob = glob('{'.$date.'}/*.xml', GLOB_BRACE);` works perfectly and makes sense now that I look at it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes of course.  Can't accept before 10 minutes though :)